# IPhone TV Out Cable Usage

Tags: iphone, television

I found a cable which one can use to connect IPhone to TV to watch videos stored in IPhone on TV. I wonder can I use this cable in a way to stream data from other devices to iphone and write an iphone app to seek the stream to play audio/video in iphone?

[The Cable.](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Scosche+-+sneakPEEK+A/V+Cable+for+Apple%26%23174%3B+iPod%26%23174%3B,+iPhone%26%23174%3B+and+iPad%26%23153%3B/1118166.p?id=1218222800547&skuId=1118166&st=iphone%20adaptor&cp=4&lp=12)

I am not sure where to go to read about the behavior of this cable as how t works. A help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You won't be able to do that due to API limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The cable is a copy of the original "Apple Composite AV Cable":
http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC748ZM/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY

The only thing you can do with the cable in addition to playing videos, is to show a UIView or your complete app on a TV. To clone your complete app you can use the TVOutManager:
https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager

I use the TVOutManager in my app and I am very happy with it :-)

Comment: You created a hope. Now precisely, would I be able to connect IPhone with my DVD player via this cable (DVD player has TV out)? If yes, can I read stream inside iphone app (from DVD player to IPhone)?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The cable is only an output and not an input. You can't get data into the iPhone. It's only possible to stream from iPhone to TV but not the other way. I'm sorry...

Comment: are you sure? the intention is to read from DVD player and not from TV.

Comment: DVD player itself has TV out so can IPhone receive the data?

Comment: No, the iPhone can't receive data, I'm very sure